# How to paste values in VBA after Z ie. AA, AB etc

Tags: excel, vba

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BC" & Row & ":EV" & Row).Copy _
     Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Row)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

it is taking the values from Column B I want it from BC

Please help

Comment: There is an "AA1" Cell

Comment: What's the value in `Row` when it fails? If it's just a number there's nothing in your posted code which would cause values to be copied from ColB

Comment: value is 16. Thats what is happening tim:(

Comment: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Then there's something else not shown in your question which is responsible for that.

Comment: Try specifying a workbook too for the two ranges. It may be that the active workbook the code is referring to now does not have the values you are expecting

Comment: Did No luck. Please help

Comment: BC16:EV16. This is what is the range

Comment: We can't help you without you showing us the full code. As @TimWilliams mentioned, something else in your code is causing the problem